# Spring security with AngularJS - 404 on logout

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, logout

I'm working with tutorial that describes how to write simple single-page app using Spring Boot, Spring Security and AngularJS: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

I cannot logout currently logged user - when I perform POST request to "/logout", I get "404 not found" - screen from Google Chrome debugger:

[image]

Why GET? I performed POST. Why "/login?logout", not "/logout"? Here is the code that is invoked when user clicks logout button:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
            $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                $location.path("/");
            }).error(function(data) {
                console.log("Logout failed")
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            });
        }
```

Spring code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class UiApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/resource")
    public Map<String, Object> home() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and().csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                            .getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }
    }

}
```

Whole AngularJS code:

```
angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute' ]).config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider
.when('/', {templateUrl : 'home.html', controller : 'home'  })
.when('/login', { templateUrl : 'login.html',   controller : 'navigation'   })
.otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

}).controller('navigation',

        function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $route) {

            $scope.tab = function(route) {
                return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
           };

            var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

                var headers = credentials ? {
                    authorization : "Basic "
                            + btoa(credentials.username + ":"
                                    + credentials.password)
                } : {};

                $http.get('user', {
                    headers : headers
                }).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.name) {
                        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    } else {
                        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    }
                    callback && callback($rootScope.authenticated);
                }).error(function() {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    callback && callback(false);
                });

            }

            authenticate();
            $scope.credentials = {};            
            $scope.login = function() {
                authenticate($scope.credentials, function(authenticated) {
                    if (authenticated) {
                        console.log("Login succeeded")
                        $location.path("/");
                        $scope.error = false;
                        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Login failed")
                        $location.path("/login");
                        $scope.error = true;
                        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    }
                })          
            };

            $scope.logout = function() {
                $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    $location.path("/");
                }).error(function(data) {
                    console.log("Logout failed")
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                });         
            }

        }).controller('home', function($scope, $http) { 
           $http.get('/resource/').success(function(data) {         
               $scope.greeting = data; }) });
```

I'm new to Spring. Here is the whole code from tutorial - doesn't work too:
https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/single

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: In case you want to understand what happened. You "get GET instead of POST" because there are actually 2 requests for logout. The first one is POST you done manually that receives a response with a redirect code to "login?logout" resource. Then GET request to this resource is performed. When you "override" logoutSuccessHandler you will exclude redirection from logout request (i.e. there will be just one POST request to "logout" resource).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact what you need is just to add a logout success handler

```
@Component
public class LogoutSuccess implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() != null) {
        try {
            httpServletRequest.getSession().invalidate();
            // you can add more codes here when the user successfully logs
            // out,
            // such as updating the database for last active.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e = null;
        }
    }

    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

}

}
```

and add a success handler to your security config

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccess).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(false).permitAll();
```

Answer (score 5):

In newer version of Spring Boot there is a class called HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler which returns HTTP 200 per default. Its JavaDoc says:

> "This is useful in REST-type scenarios where a redirect upon a
>   successful logout is not desired".

to use it write something like:

```
        //... 
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `$http.post('logout', {})` to this `$http.post('\logout')`

So it will be like this:

```
$scope.logout = function () {
    $http.post('\logout')
        .success(function () {
            // on success logic
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            // on errorlogic
        });
}
```