# Spring security with AngularJS - logout does not work

Tags: java, angularjs, google-chrome, spring-security, logout

I found the same problem and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694905/spring-security-with-angularjs-404-on-logout). But those solution have not helped me. The example you can get [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/single). As you can see example contains good description for logout in client *angular part*. But it does not provide logout processing on server part. So I checked [***LogoutSuccessHandler***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694905/spring-security-with-angularjs-404-on-logout)

```
authentication.isAuthenticated() == true
```

I tried use some experiments, but logout does not work. Tried:

```
((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication).eraseCredentials();
```

or

```
authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
```

and *.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", **"XSRF-TOKEN"**)*

```
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccess).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "XSRF-TOKEN")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll();
```

result was same. I hope someone can help me with the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Possible, this is not security issue as i thought. This is chrome handler issue. I do not know how it happens, but my firefox works correctly, and IE can process it in good way, but chrome has an leak or hack (seems so).

Question is closed in general. But if someone knows what should be fixed in chrome - please let me know. (i cleaned all cookies in chrome and cached data using _**Ctrl+Shift+Del**_ - it does not help).

Comment: I detected difference: chrome browser contains in each request header **Authorization:Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==**. possible it will help to get correct answer.

Comment: 1up for the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure, this is not security issue. This is chrome handler issue. I do not know how it happens, but my Firefox works correctly, and IE can process it in good way.

I have checked *chrome settings* and have found next: *settings* >> *Show advanced settings...* >> *Manage passwords* >> ***Auto Sign-in*** flag was turn on. I removed this flag. Problem was not solved. I changed my login in ***application.yml***. After restarting application *IE*, *Firefox* continued work as accepted (show home page\login\logout and so on), ***BUT Chrome*** asked login password in popup window (window was like system), if i do not put here login\password - i can not see any page in chrome (*Whitelabel Error Page*), but if i put in popup window my credentials - i have got authorized session. If i press logout authorization do not disappear (after reloading page i can see details for authorized users only).

So i think question is closed in general. But if someone knows what should be fixed in chrome - please let me know. (i cleaned all cookies in chrome and cached data using ***Ctrl+Shift+Del*** - it does not help).

*Add more details*
My user for application last time was **u2**. I renamed user in ***application.yml*** file to **u3**. I used chrome last time with **u2**, but server knows nothing about user **u2**. After restarting server i tried load home page with *chrome* -> than i have got *Authentication Request* pop up window in chrome. Server logs you can see below.

```
2016-08-02 20:30:35.866  INFO 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.867  INFO 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-08-02 20:30:35.883  INFO 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 16 ms
2016-08-02 20:30:35.901 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/css/**'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.901 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/js/**'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.901 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/images/**'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.901 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.901 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/error'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.902 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.903 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.903 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-08-02 20:30:35.903 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-08-02 20:30:35.906 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.906 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2583a7b2
2016-08-02 20:30:35.907 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.925 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: ''
2016-08-02 20:30:35.935 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.935 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.935 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.937 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'u2'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.939 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-08-02 20:30:35.940 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User 'u2' not found
2016-08-02 20:30:35.941 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
2016-08-02 20:30:35.941 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2016-08-02 20:30:35.941 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@32c6200d
2016-08-02 20:30:35.941 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-08-02 20:30:35.942 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Please pay attention i did not use user **u2** in this request but you can see information about this user in server logs:

```
2016-08-02 20:30:35.937 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'u2'
2016-08-02 20:30:35.939 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-08-02 20:30:35.940 DEBUG 18404 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User 'u2' not found
```

***It seems chrome provides unexpected behavior.
AND [Example](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/single) works correctly without additional changes.***

**P.S. Solution for chrome.**

I think each time if you are using chrome you need use *incognito* mode. In *incognito mode* you have no any token for first request, *incognito mode* provides expected behavior as it should be without chrome *hacks* or *workarounds*.